# How to disable automount for internal partitions?

Tags: automount

how can I disable automount for NTFS/FAT partitions from internal diskdrives in Ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 2):

Do nothing. Partitions on internal disks for which you did not specify a mount point at install time, are not automatically mounted (until you try to open them in the file manager). They will however, still show up on the launcher by default, as well as in the file manager, so that you can access them.

Answer (score 0):

You can also manage which partitions are mounted automatically at boot time by editing

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

More info about the file format can be found by typing:

```
man fstab
```